# How do I "extract" a variable from other classes or methods?

Tags: java, mysql, methods, hashmap, inner-classes

I came back to Java recently after a significant amount of time with Python, and I'm trying to get comfortable with it again. My first desired project was to make a small application where you can (firstly) log in. I am using mySQL to hold the database of usernames and passwords.

So far I have used Java's swing GUI to make a pop-up box asking for sign-in info. The entered username and password are tested against those in the SQL table.

The problem is that I am using a while loop to test the inputs against the SQL table. So the entered info is checked against every key and value in a Hashmap created from the SQL table.

I am not sure how to "extract" my variable g (the Hashmap) from the while loop and the SQL's try statement so that I can use it after it has been filled with the data from mySQL.

I am using Eclipse (Java Neon).

I've no clue how to "extract" the hashmap, and when I try to have the while loop or try statement return the hashmap, Eclipse informs me that void methods cannot return a value (clearly). However, I can not change the return type from void to HashMap)String, String> because "The return type is incompatible with ActionListener.actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)" and " implements java.awt.event.ActionListener.actionPerformed".

Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Hello0 extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1487932324102279819L;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame Demo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(350, 200);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frame.add(panel);
        placeComponents(panel);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }


    private static void placeComponents(JPanel panel) {

        panel.setLayout(null);
        JLabel userLabel = new JLabel("Username");
        userLabel.setBounds(10, 20, 80, 25);
        panel.add(userLabel);

        JTextField userText = new JTextField(20);
        userText.setBounds(100, 20, 165, 25);
        panel.add(userText);

        JLabel passwordLabel = new JLabel("Password");
        passwordLabel.setBounds(10, 50, 80, 25);
        panel.add(passwordLabel);

        JPasswordField passwordText = new JPasswordField(20);
        passwordText.setBounds(100, 50, 165, 25);
        panel.add(passwordText);

        JButton loginB = new JButton("Login");
        loginB.setBounds(10, 80, 80, 25);
        panel.add(loginB);

        loginB.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public HashMap<String, String> actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String username0 = "root";
                String password = "javaSQLmy98";
                try {

                    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javabase?useSSL=false";
                    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username0, password);
                    PreparedStatement stmt0 = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * from userids");

                    String pass0 = null;
                    String user1 = userText.getText().toString();
                    char[] pass1 = passwordText.getPassword();
                    pass0 = String.valueOf(pass1);
                    System.out.println(user1);
                    System.out.println(pass1);

                    ResultSet rs = stmt0.executeQuery();
                    rs = stmt0.executeQuery("SELECT * from userids ");
                    while (rs.next()) {

                        String user = rs.getString("username");
                        String pass = rs.getString("paswrd");

                        Map<String, String> g = new HashMap<>();
                        g.put(user, pass);
                        return g;
                        // This was the alternative: if(g.keySet().contains("Jacob") && g.values().contains("root")) {


                        /*This code below was originally outside the while loop but I could not
                        figure out how to make it work without it being inside, and accessible 
                        to the hashmap g. Now it is being checked each time the while loop 
                        is ran, with a new pair of usernames and passwords on each loop. */

                        if (user1.equals(user) && pass0.equals(pass)) {
                            System.out.println("Good!");
                        }

                        /*The problem here is that the checker IS inside the loop, so it 
                         tests the input against each of the entries in the SQL table. */
                        else {
                            System.err.println("The username or password is incorrect.");
                        }
                    }

                    connection.close();
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    System.err.println(e1.getMessage());
                }

            }
        });

    }

}
```

Cheers!

Comment: Why do you load everything into a HashMap instead of just including a WHERE clause in your SQL query?

Comment: Do you understand how to write a query in SQL to fetch the single row for the user ID, instead of looping over all the rows in the table?

Comment: @RiaanNel I am not sure how this would help. Doesn't the WHERE keyword just act as a filter?

Comment: @JimGarrison I wasn't sure how this would help either; but I believe you mean to say to do something like this:

Comment: Take the username submitted and compare it to a username in the SQL table. If it matches, check the password also. ? (In hindsight, I believe this is what @RiaanNel is suggesting also.)

Comment: @JacobAdamczyk I've added an answer that explains my suggestion in more detail.

Comment: @RiaanNel Aha! I understand more clearly now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a WHERE clause to your query, it will return only the data that matches the criteria.  In other words, the query below (obviously with the correct values) will return the specified userid entry if it exists, otherwise it will return an empty result set.

```
SELECT * from userids
WHERE userName = 'user1'
AND passwrd = 'pass1'
```

You can then do away with the entire while loop and the HashMap, and the code can be simplified as follows:

```
if (rs.next()) {
    System.out.println("Good!");
} else {
    System.err.println("The username or password is incorrect.");
}
```

Also, as suggested before, if this is anything more than a programming exercise, passwords should be hashed instead of being stored in plain text.

Comment: This is good for the specific values 'user1' and 'pass1' but how would I use the username and password input?

Comment: Either good old String concatenation along the lines of "SELECT ... " + user + " AND ..." + pass (which is bad, because it leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection), or you can use a PreparedStatement (the preferable option).

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: Did you get a solution to your problem?  If so, please mark an answer as accepted.

http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

To access `g` outside of the `while`, you need to declare it outside of the `while`, as every `{}` in Java scopes variables inside of it. Thus,

```
Map<String, String> g = new HashMap<>();
while (condition) {
    // do something
    g.put(key, value);
}
// do something with g
```

But in this case, you can do the check directly within SQL, which should be much more effective.

---

Side note:

Don't store passwords. [Don't store passwords.](https://youtu.be/8ZtInClXe1Q) [Hash+Salt passwords (or better, use a library).](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords)

Comment: Thank you for the good answer and suggestions. Declaring it outside of the while loop will create an empty Hashmap then? And then I fill it inside the while loop, but can use it outside now because of where it was declared?

Comment: @JacobAdamczyk exactly

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Map<String, String> g = new HashMap<String, String>();
while(rs.next()) {
    String user = rs.getString("username");
    String pass = rs.getString("paswrd");
    g.put(user, pass);

    .....
}
```

Note : Taking username as a key in HasmMap is not a good programming, because there can be multiple users with same name.

Comment: What other data structure would you recommend, then?

Comment: That's depends on your current requirement. you can have a Set<POJO> or if you want to go with Map, then you can go with Map<Long, POJO>. Where key will be your userID of type long and value will be POJO class.

Comment: Above POJO class will have properties like userId, userName, password etc..

Comment: On your note; if there are two equal usernames, there is a possibility for their passwords to also be the same. If this is the case, how could we make the two accounts unique?

Comment: password can be same(in your case you are taking password as value in map). i think you have better knowledge on Map. if not, try to go through Map implementations, you will get to know why we should not take username as key(if there is chance of duplicate username).